# Print table with non null values without making it shapeless

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in a database that has 9 columns. I want to print them all except the empty ones that will make my table misshapen. 1 column in first line, two in the second, etc.
If the column is null I don't want to print it.

Explanation: (imagine it as HTML table not MySQL one)

```
+------+
|  id  | -- > this is the title of empty column in the table so I won't print it .. 
+------+
|(null)| -- > this is an empty column so I won't print it too ..
--------
```

This is the best script I have so far, but it has two problems:

- It's printing the same table with the same values more than one time.
- It's printing empty columns also.

```
public function fetchAll($TableName)
       {
        $content = '';
        $keys = '';
        $values = '';
        $tablestart = '<table border="1" align="center" dir="rtl">';
        $tableend = '</table>';
        $trtd = '<tr><td>';
        $tdcloseopen = '</td><td>';
        $tdclose = '</td>';
        $trcloseopen = '</tr><tr>';
        $trclose = '</tr>';
        $com = "SELECT * FROM $TableName WHERE (m_id and m_first_name and m_last_name and m_nick and m_father_name and m_mother_name and m_age and m_gender and m_place) IS NOT NULL;";
        $send = mysql_query($com);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($send);
        if($count > 0)
       {
    while($array = mysql_fetch_array($send))
        {
            if($array[m_id] !=null)
            {
                $keys .= $tablestart.$trtd."id".$tdcloseopen;
                $values .= $trtd.$array[m_id].$tdcloseopen;
            }
            if($array[m_first_name] !=null)
            {
                $keys .= "fname".$tdcloseopen;
                $values .= $array[m_first_name].$tdcloseopen;
            }
            if($array[m_last_name] !=null)
            {
                $keys .= "lname".$tdclose.$trcloseopen;
                $values .= $array[m_last_name].$tdclose.$trcloseopen;

            }
    // i want 3 columns in each <tr> so i but this script after each (3 if statment)
            $content .= $keys.$values;
            $keys ='';
            $values = '';
            if($array[m_nick] !=null)
            {
                $keys .= "nick".$tdcloseopen;
                $values .= $array[m_nick].$tdcloseopen;
            }
            if($array[m_father_name] !=null)
            {
                $keys .= "father_name".$tdcloseopen;
                $values .= $array[m_father_name].$tdcloseopen;
            }
            if($array[m_mother_name] !=null)
            {
                $keys .= "mother_name".$tdclose.$trcloseopen;
                $values .= $array[m_mother_name].$tdclose.$trcloseopen;
            }
            $content .= $keys.$values;
            $keys ='';
            $values = '';
            if($array[m_gender] !=null)
            {
                $keys .= "gender".$tdcloseopen;
                $values .= $array[m_gender].$tdcloseopen;
            }
            if($array[m_age] !=null)
            {
                $keys .= "age".$tdcloseopen;
                $values .= $array[m_age].$tdcloseopen;
            }
            if($array[m_place] !=null)
            {
                $keys .= "place".$tdclose.$trcloseopen;
                $values .= $array[m_palce].$tdclose.$trcloseopen;
            }
            $content .= $keys.$values;
            $keys ='';
            $values = '';
                       echo $content;
                       $content ='';
        }
                }
```

Comment: If you want to leave out entire `TD` elements within rows, then you will have to calculate an appropriate `colspan` for (at least one of) the remaining cells – but why would you do that, it will not look good. To just output an _empty_ cell makes much more sense.

Comment: he want to fix his code :), if wanted only sql he would showed only sql

Comment: i want to limit the results with just non-NULL values .. with mysql or PHP it's not matter ..

Comment: and the second issue is the table shape after filtering the null column from it ..